# Comparing Source database tables to target database tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, target

I'm currently consolidating source database Q1-(say table x,table y, table z)  into a smaller number of tables in database Q2 .I need to compare the target data(in Q2) to  the source data Q1 (x,y,z). Whats the best practice  to compare/profile these consolidated target tables(in database Q2) against the  source Q1 tables?

Example :

Source Data(database Q1):

- Table x: (column a1,column b1,column c1)
- Table y: (column a2,column b2,column c2)
- Table z: (column a31,column b3,column c3)

Target Data(database Q2):

- Table A in target database contains consolidated (a1,a2,a3)
- Table B in target database contains consolidated (b1,b2,b3)
- Table C in target database contains consolidated (c1,c2,c3)

Thanks,

Comment: use redgate software

Comment: This is turning into asking for a tool question, but i concur with @mannyyysh.  Get SQL Compare.

Comment: just updated the question. sorry for the typo- I meant tables

Comment: question is still ambiguous in description you're saying Database M and in example you're specifying Table M, what this table suppose to do? and are there any relationship between table x column a1 and table y column a2

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Data Compare tool from Red-Gate or Dynamic SQL Compare, you can try them for free;

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx